# is it possible to get user location in http by anyway or https is the only solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to get user location using **http** which is throwing errors like **getCurrentPosition()** is **deprecated** and moved to **https**.I have tried different ways but none of them worked out for me.Hoping a solution for this if someone know this...

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the GEO-location?

Comment: What is your code ? What are you using to retrieve location ?

Comment: @Kootsj yeah it is

Answer (score 1):

your question is not entirely clear. Are you doing the "location lookup" via http instead of https? Or do your visitors come in via http instead of https?

Back to the question: the common method to get the geographic origin of a site visitor is to use some form of database which correlates IP-address ranges with geographies (typical and probably the one with the widest use: GeoIP). This can be wrapped in many forms in any programming language. So the "getCurrentPosition" call is most likely using some form of a IP-to-Location database.

Visitor IP: will always be available and is independent of http / https - so it will not matter whether your site is http or https or both.

getCurrentPosition: if using a local geoIP database, this one wouldn't even need to do a http or https request. It could use a local DB lookup (file based).

If however it does go to a remote service (which it looks like it does), then just use https to avoid the warning. There must be a configurable item that defines the lookup URL - change that to https.

Comment: As mentioned in the referenced "duplicate" origin, the method of choice would be to wrap this function and perform the location lookup by some other means (without using the Geolocation API by Google, where http is deprecated). Or even better (also mentioned there, turn on https via Letsencrypt)